# Laravel "{slug}" not being replaced, instead being url encoded

Tags: php, laravel, slug

I've recently embarked on learning Laravel.  In doing so I've began completing tutorials from around the web, including from youtube.  In one such tutorial I've been developing a very basic blog.  I've hit something of an impasse when working with slugs.  For some reason, it just doesn't want to work for me!

When the following code is entered in my 'routes.php' file, I have noticed that the braces '{' and '}' are automatically converted to URL encoding and the word "slug" is displayed.  Additionally, the '/' following the word posts is nowhere to be seen. This means a link will read as "http:[domain name]/posts/**%7Bslug%7D**[article name]"

```
Route::get('/posts/{slug}', [
    'as' => 'post-show', 
    'uses' => 'PostController@getIndex'
]);
```

The problem is partially resolved if I change the code thus:

```
Route::get('/posts/{slug?}', [
    'as' => 'post-show', 
    'uses' => 'PostController@getIndex'
]);
```

The word "slug" is no longer displayed as part of the URL.  However, for some reason the slug's preceding '/' is still not visible, as though eaten by the slug in question!  It now reads "http:[domain name]/posts**%7Bslug%7D**[article name]".

I'd really appreciate pointing in the right direction if anyone can lend a hand.  Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. How are you inserting these links into your view?  One way is like `{{ route('post-show', ['slug' => '123']) }}`.  [Other ways are documented online](http://laravel.com/docs/helpers#urls).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Bishop.

I'm inserting the links into my view using this method:

`@if($posts->count())
    @foreach($posts as $post)
    <article>
 <h2><a href="{{ URL::action('post-show'), $post->slug }}">{{ $post->title }}</a></h2>
 {{ Markdown::parse(Str::limit($post->body, 157)) } <a href="{{ URL::action('post-show'), $post->slug }}">read more&hellip;</a>
 </article>
        @endforeach
@endif`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, the way you're calling the action is incorrect.  Try this view code:

```
@if ($posts->count())
  @foreach ($posts as $post)
    <article>
      <h2><a href="{{ route('post-show', ['slug' => $post->slug]) }}">{{ $post->title }}</a></h2>  
      {{ Markdown::parse(Str::limit($post->body, 157)) }}
      <a href="{{ route('post-show', ['slug' => $post->slug]) }}">read more&hellip;</a>
    </article>
  @endforeach
@endif
```

I am not near a terminal to test this, but it should get you closer. The problems this code addresses are:

1. To generate a URL using the route *name*, use `route`.  Your code was using `action`.
2. To pass a parameter and fill in the "{slug}", you pass an array as the second argument to `route` (and `action` for that matter).  Your code was neither passing an array nor passing the value into the function.
3. You were missing a `}` after the `Markdown::parse`, but that may have been a copy & paste error.

Comment: That's done the trick!  And yes, at least the missing `}` was down to a copy and paste error!

The odd thing is, I was just following a tutorial.  The original code seemed to work in that.